# How to Add Column (script) transform that queries another column for content

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I’m looking for a simple expression that puts a ‘1’ in column E if ‘SomeContent’ is contained in column D.  I’m doing this in Azure ML Workbench through their Add Column (script) function.  Here’s some examples they give.

```
row.ColumnA + row.ColumnB is the same as row["ColumnA"] + row["ColumnB"] 
1 if row.ColumnA < 4 else 2 
datetime.datetime.now() 
float(row.ColumnA) / float(row.ColumnB - 1) 
'Bad' if pd.isnull(row.ColumnA) else 'Good'
```

Any ideas on a 1 line script I could use for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without really knowing what you want to look for in column 'D', I still think you can find all the information you need in the examples they give.

The script is being wrapped by a function that collects the value you calculate/provide and puts it in the new column. This assignment happens for each row individually. The value could be a static value, an arbitrary calculation, or it could be dependent on the values in the other columns for the specific row.

In the "Hint" section, you can see two different ways of obtaining the values from the other rows:

```
The current row is referenced using 'row' and then a column qualifier, for example row.colname or row['colname'].
```

In your case, you obtain the value for column 'D' either by `row.D` or `row['D']`

After that, all you need to do is come up with the specific logic for ensuring if 'SomeContent' is contained in column 'D' for that specific row. In your case, the '1 line script' would look something like this:

```
1 if [logic ensuring 'SomeContent' is contained in row.D] else 0
```

If you need help with the logic, you need to provide more specific examples.

You can read more in the Azure Machine Learning Documentation:

[Sample of custom column transforms (Python)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/data-prep-appendix10-sample-custom-column-transforms-python)

[Data Preparations Python extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/desktop-workbench/data-prep-python-extensibility-overview)

Hope this helps